# npm install inside docker build

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, networking, virtual-machine

I am dockerising a `nodejs` application on `ubuntu 17.10` locally with Oracle VM Virtualbox.

I have mentioned following steps in Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/Downloads/nodejs/workdirectory
COPY package.json /home/ubuntu/Downloads/nodejs/workdirectory
RUN npm install
COPY . /home/ubuntu/Downloads/nodejs/workdirectory
CMD node index.js
EXPOSE 8081
```

I am facing following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/nodejs/application$ sudo docker build -t acc/nodejsapp2:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:7
 ---> d9aed20b68a4
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/Downloads/nodejs/workdirectory
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0efd4825ed8f
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json /home/ubuntu/Downloads/nodejs/workdirectory
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c1ef3d889b5
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in f0bbfa9920cb
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@4.2.0
npm info using node@v7.10.1
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 8:46:04 AM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 8:46:54 AM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm info attempt registry request try #3 at 8:48:34 AM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-02T08_49_14_320Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

As per many articles in stackoverflow,

1)I have made changes in etc/hosts of Ubuntu as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-VirtualBox
151.101.16.162 registry.npmjs.org

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

2)I also made entry in /etc/default/docker as:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 151.101.16.162"
```

It is not working in docker build.
How can i proceed with steps to rectify it?

Comment: What does `/root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-02T08_49_14_320Z-debug.log` say?

Comment: @helvete nothing is getting created in this path. `ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/etc/default$ cd /root
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/root$ ls
Desktop
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/root$ cd .npm
bash: cd: .npm: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/root$`

Comment: I mean within the docker container, not the host system. I am almost sure there will be some hints on what's wrong, otherwise `npm` wouldn't write it and suggest appending it (actually - that part you haven't done)

Comment: Anyway, you can try: not running the container command as root as it often creates problems difficult to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly follow the following steps for rectifying the error in Ubuntu occurred in above:

1)Find out the ip of the Ethernet network by using ifconfig.

```
enp0s4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet **10.X.X.XX**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.8.89.898
```

2)Create a new network and enable **Default IP when binding container ports** and mention the above ip address.

```
docker network create -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="10.X.X.XX" my-network
```

3)Use this newly created network to build the docker image:

```
docker build --network my-network -t hello-world .
```